# TFS 2013 tbl_Branch Status without API

Tags: tfs

I have a need to get a list of all branches with paths and IsDeleted status. I can do this with the API from a development environment, but I will be unable to use the API in the production environment. A workaround is to query the TFS database for the data I need. I found the branches table (tbl_Branches), but it doesn't have a status column. I am not sure what I need to join on to find the status.

I am looking for the status that is from the property branchObject.Properties.RootItem.IsDeleted if using the API.

Does anyone know what to look at to get the same status for the branch as what the API uses?

Thank you.

Comment: You should not query TFS databases directly. It is unsupported, undocumented, and not recommended.

Answer (score 0):

The branches are tracked as items. So you need to join "tbl_Version" to get all the versions for the branches. The entries with "DeletionID" > 0 means ther are/were deleted. However, we don't recommend to query TFS Database directly just as Daniel mentioned in the comments. You should avoid this if you have any other workaround.